# Collect user input till a specific keyword is entered

Tags: python

I want to write a program to:

- Collect unique data from user
- If data is already there print some error message
- Stop collecting data if he types 'exit'

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What did you try already? Please show some code.

Comment: This seems reasonably easy ... Is there anything in particular that is giving you a hard time?  Some people might be willing to just give you the code, but I for one would rather try to understand where you're having trouble and help you around that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a basic question, I am curious to know what you tried before asking.

```
keywords = set()
while 'exit' not in keywords:
    keywords.add(input('Enter keyword: '))
```

Since `keywords` is a set, you will never have duplicate data.

Answer (score 1):

```
dic={}
while 1:

    x=raw_input()

    if x=="exit":
        break
    elif (x in dic.keys()):
        print "Error:input already there"
    else:
        dic[x]=1
print dic
```

Something like this can help.